# Implied Volatility Calculation

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility

I want to calculate the implied volatility from the option data that I took from Bloomberg (call Option written on S&P500 index with the maturity of 19-Dec-2009 and strike of 1300), but volatility comes out to be zero. Do you have any ideas how I can calculate the volatility or correct the data?

1. As the risk free rate I normally use the 3 month TBill rate.
2. As the Last price of the option I use the average of the Bid and Ask Prices (Bloomberg last price is not available for the most of the data points).

Thank you.

```
Date      Bid Price Underlying Interest Rate    Time to Maturity    Ask Price   Last Price
22/12/2006  272.5   1411.73999  0.055555        2.989041096          276.5       274.5  
26/12/2006  278.5   1417.869995 0.055463        2.978082192          282.5       280.5  
27/12/2006  285.8   1427.709961 0.055666        2.975342466          289.8       287.8  
28/12/2006  285.1   1425.089966 0.05538         2.97260274           289.1       287.1
```

Comment: I think it could be helpful if you state the method you used for computing the IVs.

Comment: @Finance_Newbie, I am using the Black Scholes Option Pricing model to find the implied volatility.

Comment: I learned that it is not possible to solve the BS-formula implicitly for the implied volatility. Hence, it needs to be done numerically. Consequently, I asked for the numerical procedure you used. It would be even better if you supply some code and the software you are using.

Comment: I used two methods, first one is matlabs internal program blsimpv, the other one is optimization in excel (just simple min problem).

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/how-to-compute-implied-volatility-calculation. Use Newton Raphson to solve for the implied volatility.

Comment: OK, someone flagged and said: it's about why this example doesn't work. That might be of interest, kdragger does a good suggestion. If that is not the cause we probably need more information.

Comment: I would appreciate any feedback on @BobJansen comment, it would great to know what is wrong with the above numbers.

Answer (score 3):

First, as far as I can tell, you are not taking into account dividends. 
Second, If you simply take the forward price of the SPX @ $5.5\%$ which is what you are using, you get $1411 \cdot \text{exp}(0.055 \cdot 2.99) = 1663$.

Given a strike of $1300$, the call should have an intrinsic value of $1663-1300= 363$. You have a price of $272$. The price is less than the intrinsic value of the option, therefore no matter what methodology you use, $IV = 0$.

Comment: Isn't the intrinsic value be the difference between the underlying and the strike? (1411 - 1300) ?

Comment: @StudentT I was not able to find the reference to the above calculations either. By the way I was able to find the implied volatility for the option from the OVME function of Bloomberg. But unfortunately (as I was informed there is no automatized process to take all the implied volatility numbers, it must be done by hand).

Comment: @Azer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_value_(finance)

Answer (score 1):

[See this resource at github , it uses different methods to calculate IV programmatically](https://github.com/jamesmawm/Options-Modelling/blob/master/BS.py)