# How to calculate Implied Volatility for out-of-the-money options?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, implied-volatility

I'm trying to calculate the implied volatility for out-of-the-money options, and to a lesser extent, in-the-money options. Most of the literature estimations I could find for implied volatility were for at-the-money options.

In other words, given $C(s,t)$, $S$, and $Ke^{-r(T-t)}$, related by:

$$C(s,t) = SN(d_1) - N(d_2)Ke^{-r(T-t)}$$
$$d_1 = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\left(\log(S/K)+\left(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)\left(T-t\right)\right)$$
$$d_2 = d_1 - \sigma\sqrt{T-t}$$

I'm trying to calculate $\sigma$. My preliminary investigations have revealed no closed-form solution, so I've resolved to a numerical approximation instead, but I haven't found any literature results on this approximation.

I would be glad if anyone could refer me to any useful approximations or other results. Other comments on this are also welcome as it's a tricky topic.

Comment: Newton's method, or the more elementary bi-section method, which you can find in any math finance book.

Comment: Strictly speaking the CDF $N(d_{1,2})$ is already not in closed form.

Comment: Are you looking specifically at OTM options? There is a general question on IV computations [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/how-to-compute-implied-volatility-calculation).

Comment: If you use R then this link could be useful. This is an article that contains a code to calculate IV using bi-section method http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-only-thing-smiling-today-is-volatility/

Answer (score 6):

Peter Jaeckel has written various papers on this. "by implication" and "Let's be rational" are the most recent ones. He also provides code on his website [www.jaeckel.org](http://www.jaeckel.org).

(Note: the question asked for literature.)

Answer (score 3):

Look on Google for **Asymptotic behavior of Implied Volatility Near Infinity**

you will find results like :

$$I(K) \stackrel{K\to\infty}{=} \sqrt{\frac{2}{T}}\left(\sqrt{\ln \frac{K}{C(K)}}-\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{C(K)}}\right) +\text{O}_{K\to \infty}\left(\frac{\ln\ln\frac{1}{C(K)}}{\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{C(K)}}}\right)$$

Comment: What is exactly going to infinity?

Comment: strike goes to $\infty$

Comment: this is an approximation for a deep out-of-the money call option

Answer (score 2):

One more reference that I know is

[Li and Lee (2009)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/14697680902849361)
[[download]](https://ssrn.com/abstract=1027282)

An adaptive successive over-relaxation method for computing the Black–Scholes implied volatility