# Log-normal Volatility Approximation

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility

In a comment to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/28186/downward-sloping-smile-in-normal-model), it is mentioned that, under the log-normal distribution, 
\begin{align*}
vol(k) \approx vol(atm) \times \sqrt{\frac{atm}{k}}.
\end{align*}
Here, $k$ is the strike, $atm$ is the at-the-money strike, and $vol(k)$ is the implied volatility corresponding to strike $k$. I have difficulty to derive this approximation. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @dm63: any suggestion?

Comment: Gordon, I think Mark Joshi  can answer your question without any formula

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: any reference?

Comment: I 'm trying to find it.Unfortunately, I lost it.

Comment: Thanks @BehrouzMaleki. This question (http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25407/how-to-calculate-implied-volatility-for-out-of-the-money-options/25432#25432) and this question (http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/how-to-compute-implied-volatility-calculation) provide a few clues. But there is such approximation as in the question.

Comment: From memory I think this is addressed in Blyth and Uglum "Rates of Skew" in Risk Magazine from about 10 years ago.

Comment: The intuition is that if there is a constant normalized local vol s, then the local lognormal vol is initially s/A, where A is the current at the money level.   The local lognormal vol around the strike is s/K.  So on a path that starts at the current market price and ends around the strike, the geometric average local lognormal vol is s/sqrt(AK).  Since the current atm lognormal vol , sigma= s/A, the above is equal to sigma*sqrt(A/K).  The key issue to be proved is that the average over all paths is the same as the specific path mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 3 of this document ad-co.com/analytics_docs/ALevin_QP_2012.pdf shows the result, originally given in Risk Magazine by Blyth and Uglum.

The intuition for the formula is given in my comment above.  The original motivation for such a formula was for interest rate options in the 1990s.  Everyone had a lognormal pricing model, but traders understood that the distribution of interest rates may be closer to normal.  Hence we needed a formula to plug in the right lognormal vol into our models.