# What's the typical markup on quoted exotics, and what drives this premium?

Tags: options, market-making, exotics, quote

I'm curious about the typical markup on quoted exotic options as well as what drives this premium.

You call up an options desk for a quote, and they'll give you a spread that reflects their market on the vol plus a bunch of other things. (This spread might be deflected based on inventory, but let's ignore this aspect for a second.) Generally, what goes into the spread apart from the uncertainty about the forward vol? Is anything other than adverse selection priced in on top of the vol spread?

For a more concrete example, if I asked a desk to quote me a $1 strike 5-years-to-expiry call on Amazon, would they price this like pure delta? If there's a premium, what's driving that? What if I told the desk that I was committed to *buying* the option; would they still put a premium on the call?

For a more complex example, if I asked a desk to quote me a $1 strike perpetual call option on Amazon that can't be exercised for the next 5 years, would they price this like pure delta? If there's a premium, what's driving that (illiquidity of the exotic? adverse selection?) What if I told the desk that I was committed to *buying* the perpetual; would they still put a premium on the call?

Comment: I think that uncertainty about the forward vol *of the underlying* is the main premium driver, as that uncertainty is directly linked to the cost of delta and gamma hedging, as alluded to in this answer [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/why-do-institutional-traders-prefer-short-selling-instead-of-buying-puts/60772#60772). Aside from the forward vol uncertainty, it would be the liquidity *of (all other) options* on the same underlying (other options cost = vega hedging cost). Amazon options are liquid, so the bid-offer spread should be tighter than on smaller names.