# Calibrating Heston model using implied volatilities

Tags: options, option-pricing, heston, calibration, modelling

I'm trying to understand how the authers of a paper calibrated their model.

We got data on European type options on the
S&P500-index period from early 2005 to mid-2009. We have daily data on option
prices; 182 implied volatilities for each day in our data-set with moneyness from -30%
to +30% (of current underlying) and between one month and three years to expiry
(See the image attached below as an example for 31-jul-2009)

I want to calibrate a Heston Model to this data by minimizing

\begin{align}
\sum_{t,k}(IV_{t,k}-IV_{t,k}^{\Theta})^2 
\end{align}
where $IV_{t,k}$ and $IV_{t,k}^\Theta$ are  the quoted and model implied
volatilities, respectively. (t,k) are the maturity-strike combinations.

My question is:

> How do I compute $IV_{t,k}^{\Theta}$ using the data given in the screenshot?

[image]

EDIT:

I want to use the first method and calculate the BS prices.

So for example consider the call from 31-Jul-2009 with strike 1283.72 and tenor = 3M.

I use the following function:

blackscholes(call,
S0,
K,
r,
time till expiration in years,
volatility, dividend_yield)

blackscholes(call,
987.48,
1283.72,
0.47%,
0.25,
16.8%,
2.36%)

Are these the correct values for this example? (I took the ZeroRate as risk-free interest rate)

And then do the same for every combination of strikes and tenors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implied volatility based moneyness has no meaning in Heston model. There are two possible solutions:

1. Use the (quoted) implied volatility and compute the quoted option price $C_{t,k}$ with the Black-Scholes-Model. Calibrate the Heston model by minimizing
   $$\sqrt{\sum_{t,k}\left( C_{t,k} - C_{t,k}^{\Theta} \right)^2}$$
2. Compute the option price $C_{t,k}^{\Theta}$ bases on your Heston Model. Use the Black-Scholes-Model to get the corresponding implied volatility $IV(C_{t,k}^{\Theta})$. For the details see [A simple formula for calculating implied volatility?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/a-simple-formula-for-calculating-implied-volatility)

The concept of implied volatility is in fact inseparable from the Black-Scholes-Model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edited my question and added an example. I want to use the 1. method. Can you tell me if these are the correct values to put in the Black Scholes pricing formula?

Comment: Yes that seems to be correct. I would however advise you to check the strike prices. The displayed strikes aren't even which means they are probably not traded but are calculated to match some delta (1%, 10%, 20%, 25%, 30%, ...). If that is the case the different tenors will have different strike prices associated with the delta levels.