# Expected profit from straddle and its standard deviation

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, implied-volatility

I was reading "Paul Wilmott introduces quantitative finance". In chapter 10 page 227 he states that:

If you buy an at-the-money straddle close to expiry the profit you expect to make from this strategy is approx. 
$$\sqrt{2(T-t)/\pi}(\sigma - \sigma_{\text{implied}})S$$
and its standard deviation of the profit (the risk) is approx. 
$$\sqrt{1-(2/\pi)}\sigma S\sqrt{T-t},$$
where $\sigma$ is the actual volatility, $\sigma_{\text{implied}}$ is the BSM implied volatility, $t$ is current time and $T$ is the maturity time.

I can't figure out how to derive these results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That does not look right. Isn't it $(\sigma^2-\sigma_{implied}^2)$ ?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/1154/).

Comment: @msitt thank you so much for your answer! That sure helped a lot.